# Proof of midpoint theorem in hyperbolas/conics

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Please help me find a proof for the **midpoint theorem** in hyperbolas (or conics in general).

*All midpoints of parallel chords in a hyperbola/conic are located on a common line.*

Motivation: I study mathematics for teaching and we are doing some basic geometry. We covered hyperbolas on a basic level, i.e. tangents and intersections with hyperbolas. We also discussed the midpoint theorem in hyperbolas, but unfortunately I haven't found a proof that would be comprehensible to high school students. My first idea is to find two midpoints of parallel chords and show that they are located on the same line.

[image: Illustration 1]

[image: Illustration 2]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JoséCarlosSantos, I added my motivation for the question and an idea for the proof.

Comment: I think [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Locus_of_Midpoints_of_Parallel_Chords_of_Central_Conic_passes_through_Center) should be understandable at high school level as it only uses basic analytic geometry and some easy computations. Let me know if you need some clarification about it

Comment: @david_sap I don't agree 1) That it's easily understandable 2) Worst than that, the theorem given there is not the theorem given in this question : it doesn't mention the fact that the locus is a strght line !

Comment: @JeanMarie 1) Fair enough, I'm not a teacher and maybe my high school memories are too remote 2) It does. In the second to last paragraph it clearly mentions the linear dependence between x and y

Comment: If you are interested in a synthetic proof, there is one on page 63 of this book: https://dokumen.tips/documents/geometry-of-conics.html?page=70 It is written for an ellipse, but it also works for hyperbolas and parabolas, because it only uses the focus/directrix property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Fig. 1: *If secant lines have a common slope $m$, all the midpoints of their intersection points are aligned on a line with slope $\tfrac{1}{m}$.*

As you ask the question in the framework of teachers' training, I would advise to take the simplest hyperbola, i.e., the equilateral hyperbola, and restrict the study to its upper branch with equation

$$y=\sqrt{1+x^2}\tag{1}$$

Consider parallel lines having equation

$$y=mx+p\tag{2}$$

($m$ fixed, variable $p$). Let us consider the intersection points $P_k(x_k,y_k)$ $(k=1,2)$ of this branch of hyperbola with these lines (when these points exist) ; their abscissas $x_k$ are solutions of the following equation:

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}=mx+p$$

(I jump over details that are evident to us ; some recalls are probably necessary here for your students ). Otherwise said, they are solutions of the quadratic equation :

$$\underbrace{(1-m^2)}_a x^2+\underbrace{(-2mp)}_b x+\underbrace{(1-p^2)}_c=0$$

The half-sum of the roots is classicaly given by

$$x_h=-\tfrac{b}{a}=\underbrace{\tfrac{m}{1-m^2}}_k p\tag{3}$$

(no need to compute explicitly the roots), and $x_h$ is the abscissa of the midpoint. Plugging expression (3) into (2) gives the ordinate of the midpoint :

$$y_h=m x_h + p = \tfrac{m^2}{1-m^2} p + p = \tfrac{1}{1-m^2} p \tag{4}$$

By elimination of $p$ between equations (3) and (4), we get a linear correspondence

$$x_h=m y_h$$

Therefore, the locus *belongs* to the straight line $y=\frac{1}{m}x.$

Why *belongs* instead of *is* ? One can verify graphically that this line isn't exactly the locus : one has to eliminate a line segment. The students can be asked here : has algebra "lied" ? Answer : evidently no ; look at the quadratic equation : has it always solutions ? Etc.

**Essential remark (done by Intelligenci Pauca):** Had we taken, instead of (1) the equilateral hyperbola under the form $y=\frac{1}{x}$, the computations are (even) simpler with the remarkable fact that lines with common equation (2) with slope $m$ generate a midpoints' locus with slope $-m$, This correspondence :

$$m  \ \ \leftrightarrow \ \ -m \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(opposite slope)}$$

mirroring the correspondence :

$$m  \ \ \leftrightarrow \ \ \frac{1}{m} \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(inverse slope)}$$

obtained above.

Remark 1 : The result has been obtained for this particular case of (equilateral) hyperbola ; it can be extended to *any* hyperbola by using an affine transformation, knowing that affine transformations preserve parallelism and midpoints.

Remark 2 : Behind this property is hidden the concept of duality ; see also ["conjugate diameters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_diameters).

Comment: You could make things even simpler by considering the equation $xy=a$. In that case the slope of chord $P_1P_2$, with midpoint $M$, is the opposite of the slope of line $OM$.

Comment: @intelligenti pauca I have included your excellent suggestion into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The equation of a hyperbola or an ellipse centered at the origin is given by

$r^T Q r = 1$

where $ Q $ is a symmetric $2 \times 2 $ matrix.  Now consider a line passing through $p_0$ and having a direction vector $ v_1$, then it is given parametrically by,

$r = p_0 + t v_1$

Plug this into the equation of the hyperbola (or ellipse) you get

$ (p_0 + t v_1)^T Q (p_0 + t v_1) = 1 $

Expanding,

$t^2 (v_1^T Q v_1) + 2 t p_0^T Q v_1 + p_0^T Q p_0 - 1 = 0 $

If the line intersects the hyperbola (ellipse), the roots of this quadratic equation are $ t_1, t_2 $ that correspond to two points on the line

$r_1 = p_0 + t_1 v_1 , \ r_2 = p_0 + t_2 v_1 $

The midpoint of $r_1, r_2$ is given by

$ r^* = p_0 + \left( \dfrac{t_1 + t_2}{2} \right) v_1 $

And thus corresponds to a value of $t$ that is the midpoint of $(t_1, t_2)$ , the two roots of the quadratic equation, and we know that this is given by $\dfrac{-B}{2 A} $ , i.e.

$t^* =   - \dfrac{p_0^T Q v_1}{ v_1^T Q v_1 } $

Hence, explicitly, the midpoint is given by,

$r^* = p_0 - v_1 \dfrac{v_1^T Q p_0}{  v_1^T Q v_1 } = \left( I - \dfrac{v_1 v_1^T Q}{  v_1^T Q v_1} \right) p_0 = A p_0 $

Now let $v_2$ be perpendicular to $v_1$, then we can write

$p_0 =  t v_1 +  s v_2 $

It follows that the midpoint with this $p_0$ is given by

$r^* = A ( t v_1 + s v_2) =  t A v_1 + s A v_2 $

it is easy to check that $A v_1 = 0$ , therefore,

$r^* = s A v_2$

which is an equation of a **straight line** passing through the origin (which is the center of the hyperbola (or ellipse) ) and having a direction vector $A v_2$.  This completes the proof.

For a parabola, similar arguments applied the parabola model lead to the same conclusion.

For completeness, I will include the parabola case.

The parabola algebraic equation is

$(r - V)^T Q (r - V) + b^T (r - V) = 0$

where $V$ is the vertex of the parabola, and $Q = R D R^T$ with $D = \text{ diag}\{ a, 0 \}$ and $R$ a rotation matrix, and $b^T = b_0^T R$ , where $b_0= [0, -1]^T$, so $b = R^T b_0$.

Again a straight line is given by

$r = p_0 + t v_1$

Plug this in, you get

$(p_0 - V + t v_1) Q (p_0 - V + t v_1) + b^T (p_0 - V + t v_1) = 0 $

which is a quadratic equation in $t$, and again the midpoint of the two intersections corresponds to the midpoint of $t_1, t_2$ the two roots
of this quadratic, which occurs at

$-\dfrac{B}{2A} = - \dfrac{ 2(p_0 - V)^T Q v_1 + b^T v_1 }{  2 v_1^T Q v_1} = - \dfrac{ (2(p_0 - V)^T Q + b^T ) v_1 }{ 2 v_1^T Q v_1}$

Therefore, the midpoint is given by,

$r^* = p_0 - v_1 \dfrac{ \left( 2(p_0 -V)^T Q + b^T \right) v_1 } { 2 v_1^T Q v_1 }$

After simple manipulation, this reduces to,

$r^*= v_1 \dfrac{2 V^T Q v_1- b^T v_1  }{ 2 v_1^T Q v_1 } + \left(I - \dfrac{ v_1 v_1^T Q }{v_1^T Q v_1} \right) p_0 $

written compactly,

$r^* = p_1 + A p_0 $

where

$p_1 =v_1 \dfrac{  2 V^T Q v_1 - b^T v_1  }{ 2 v_1^T Q v_1 } $

and

$ A = I - \dfrac{ v_1 v_1^T Q }{v_1^T Q v_1} $

Using $v_2$, a perpendicular vector to $v_1$ we can express $p_0$ as follows

$p_0 = t v_1 + s v_2 $

Using the fact that $A v_1 = 0 $, the midpoint is given by

$r^* = p_1 + s A v_2 $

which is a **straight line** passing through $p_1$ and having a direction vector $A v_2$.